# Elegant way to combine two arrays pairwise in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I like to combine two generic arrays pairwise by a `BiFunction`. Here you see the naive implementation:

```
<A,B,C> C[] combine(A[] as, B[] bs, BiFunction<A,B,C> op) {
    if (as.length == bs.length) {
        C[] cs = (C[]) new Object[as.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
            cs[i] = op.apply(as[i], bs[i]);
        }
        return cs;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this without a for-loop - maybe with [Java 8 `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). I would be happy about your suggestions.

Comment: While Aominè provided stream based version of your loop, I don't think it is more elegant. But it opens possibility of parallel processing if you add `.parallel()` after `.range(..)` so using that approach may be better in multiprocessor environment.

Comment: You can use Guava's [`Streams.zip()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

Comment: You should not be suppressing that warning, btw. It's bound to blow up in your face sooner or later.

Comment: An alternative to suppressing the exception is to provide an `IntFunction<C[]>` to the method, and use it to create the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method:

```
C[] cs = (C[]) new Object[as.length];
Arrays.setAll(cs, i -> op.apply(as[i], bs[i]));
```

Or, if `op` is very expensive to compute, you can also use `Arrays.parallelSetAll`.

Answer (score 4):

you can use an [IntStream.range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to generate the indices and then operate on that.

```
C[] cs = (C[])IntStream.range(0, as.length)
                       .mapToObj(i -> op.apply(as[i], bs[i]))
                       .toArray();
```